# Как загружать и брать PIL.Image в буфер обмена?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, clipboard

Как загрузить объект класса `PIL.Image` в буфер обмена, а потом взять обратно?

Находил решение, но там используется `win32clipboard`, а я работаю на *ubuntu* *18.04*, и мне надо что бы мой код работал и на *Windows* и на *Linux*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть пример, который должен вам помочь.

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import  QMimeData 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDialog, QGridLayout, QLabel, QPushButton)
from PyQt5.QtGui     import  QPixmap

class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)

        textCopyButton   = QPushButton("&Copy Text")
        textPasteButton  = QPushButton("Paste &Text")
        htmlCopyButton   = QPushButton("C&opy HTML")
        htmlPasteButton  = QPushButton("Paste &HTML")
        imageCopyButton  = QPushButton("Co&py Image")
        imagePasteButton = QPushButton("Paste &Image")
        self.textLabel   = QLabel("Original text")
        self.imageLabel  = QLabel()

        self.imageLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap(os.path.join(
            os.getcwd(), "images/close.ico")))

        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(textCopyButton,   0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(imageCopyButton,  0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(htmlCopyButton,   0, 2)
        layout.addWidget(textPasteButton,  1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(imagePasteButton, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(htmlPasteButton,  1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.textLabel,   2, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.imageLabel,  2, 2)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        textCopyButton.clicked.connect(self.copyText)
        textPasteButton.clicked.connect(self.pasteText)
        htmlCopyButton.clicked.connect(self.copyHtml)
        htmlPasteButton.clicked.connect(self.pasteHtml)
        imageCopyButton.clicked.connect(self.copyImage)
        imagePasteButton.clicked.connect(self.pasteImage)

        self.setWindowTitle("Clipboard")

    def copyText(self):
        clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
        clipboard.setText("I've been clipped!")

    def pasteText(self):
        clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
        self.textLabel.setText(clipboard.text())

    def copyImage(self):
        clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
        clipboard.setPixmap(QPixmap(os.path.join(
            os.path.dirname(__file__), "./images/python.png")))

    def pasteImage(self):
        clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
        self.imageLabel.setPixmap(clipboard.pixmap())

    def copyHtml(self):
        mimeData  = QMimeData()
        mimeData.setHtml("<b>Bold and <font color=red>Red</font></b>")
        clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
        clipboard.setMimeData(mimeData)

    def pasteHtml(self):
        clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
        mimeData  = clipboard.mimeData()
        if mimeData.hasHtml():
            self.textLabel.setText(mimeData.html())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Form()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]