# Как сохранить файл в буфер обмена?

Tags: python, изображения, clipboard

Я хочу сохранить файл (именно ФАЙЛ) в буфер обмена, чтобы в будущем комбинацией Ctrl+V вставить его в тот же ВКонтакте или Discord. Ту же картинку, текстовый файл или видео я хочу сохранить в буфер с дальнейшей целью вставить его в браузер. Помогите, если возможно
P.S. Не кидайте код с BytesIO - он не работает!

Comment: Глянь в сторону библиотеки PyAutoGUI в связке со встроенной библиотекой os. Или вот ещё вариант: 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1040676/383178

Comment: @SlayerLeon Я уже взглянул на неё. Остановился на том, чтобы просто перетаскивать картинку в окно Discord.